# A problem with asp.net output caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am new in ASP.NET, currently I am learning about output caching. So at my page's Page_Load event I have assigned current time to Label control

```
myLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

and declared page directive :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="30" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

But then when I refresh the page, the time displayed on the label is also refreshed. Is it a correct behavior?  As I understand, the page must be cached and returned the cached copy without time changing.

Comment: Your example (once I added in the missing % at the end of the page directive) works for me in a test page - the time is not refreshed.

Comment: thanks Jason, but the problem was not in the missing % , i was using Trace="true", without tracing the date is not refreshing